# Smoke detector giving false alerts

Tags: smoke-detectors

At home, we have two smoke detectors: one on the ground floor and one on the first floor. The problem is that the one at the first floor gives a lot of false alerts (and the one at the ground floor never does). We already replaced it twice, but it keeps giving false alerts, so it might have to do something with the position of it.

- It gives most false alerts at night (I don't know if this matters, but I add it here anyway).
- It is very close to a lamp and to a closet.
- We occasionally test it and remove the dust with a vacuum cleaner, but it still gives many false alerts.

Why is it giving false alerts? Does it have to do with the position?

Comment: Is this a combination CO/Smoke detector? Is it hard wired or have you tested placing it in other locations to see if you still get false alerts? Is it really an alert and not a low battery chirp (which tends to be more common at night when it's colder and batteries are weaker). Do you do a lot of cooking that may result in smoke from food? Do you burn fires in a fireplace that might result in smoke gathering in the house?

Comment: @BMitch I don't know whether it is a combination, I don't have the package anymore. It is an alert, because it keeps beeping until we stop it, which is not the case for low battery chirps. And all cooking happens at the ground floor. We burn fires sometimes, but the smoke doesn't go to the whole house and it also happens if we don't burn fires.

Comment: If it's detecting CO, that's odorless and can kill you. If it's wired, it could be picking up a stray signal and reporting that it believes another detector is going off.

Comment: No, it's not wired, and I think the chance of CO is low, because our boiler is in the cave and that's well ventilated.

Comment: And because I think the boiler is the only source that can give CO, it would pass the ground floor smoke detector first.

Comment: See also: [What besides smoke might trigger a hardwired smoke detector?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/29317/2196)